# running a javaFX application

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

when I run the application the output is like that:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Users\HP\IdeaProjects\HelloWorldFX\out\production\HelloWorldFX
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: FirstWindow.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)
```

I've downloaded and installed the javaFX but still not getting the output

```
public class FirstWindow extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)  {

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Button("OK"),300,300);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("First Window!!");
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

what I was expecting to occur is a window 
can someone help me fix this problem?

Comment: FirstWindow must be in a named package is what the error tells you :-)

Comment: @kleopatra how can I solve this problem?

Comment: move it to a named package - you might consider reading up on some java language basics :)