# Running JavaFX Application from IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

Versions

> openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.10)
>
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.10, mixed
> mode, sharing)
>
> IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.2 (Ultimate Edition) Build #IU-211.7442.40, built
> on May 31, 2021
>
> JavaFX SDK 11.0.2

Hey guys, first I want to say that this question was somewhat asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51478675/13306171) I followed all the steps that the correct answer gives, and end up with this error:

```
Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x6c5aff76) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x6c5aff76
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
    at KiloConverter.start(KiloConverter.java:12)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
```

I am somewhat of a beginner with Java, and I am doing this project for a college course. I can build the application, but cannot run it. Like I said, I followed all the steps the previous answer gave, to no avail.

Please if possible, don't tell me to "read up on the basics" like I saw [other people answer before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55432836/13306171). I just am not sure why my code won't run for my final project.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: As you say you are just beginning Java, your life would be easier if you leave out modules from the picture for now. As a test, make a backup copy of `module-info.java` somewhere and remove it from your project.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54292408/2478398) and [this bug](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/548).

Comment: @tevemadar The nature of the error indicates the OP does not have a `module-info` descriptor. Or at least is not launching their application as a module.

Comment: It would be easier to advise if you included the sample project.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention you're a beginner in Java I first recommend reading this Q&A: [What is a stack trace, and how can I use it to debug my application errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors). Then when you look back at your stack trace you'll see the fundamental error you're getting is:

```java
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x6c5aff76) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x6c5aff76
```

This is a module-related error. You may want to read [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) to familiarize yourself with modules.

In this case the error occurs because the `javafx.fxml` module is being found on the class-path while the `javafx.graphics` module is being found on the module-path. In other words, the `javafx.fxml` module is failing to be resolved as a *named module* but its code is still being found in the *unnamed module*. This breaks the qualified *exports* and qualified *opens* directives that `javafx.graphics` may give to `javafx.fxml` and the result is the `IllegalAccessError`.

You need to make sure the `javafx.fxml` module is actually resolved as a module. There are at least two ways to do this:

1. Include `javafx.fxml` in your `--add-modules` JVM argument.
2. Make your code modular by adding a `module-info.java` file:

   ```java
   // or whatever you want to name your module
   module app {
     requires javafx.controls;
     requires javafx.fxml;

     // export your Application subclass's package to at least javafx.graphics
     exports com.example.app to javafx.graphics;

     // open your FXML controller package(s) to at least javafx.fxml (allows reflective access)
     opens com.example.app.controllers to javafx.fxml;
   }
   ```

   And launch your application as a module. For example, this is what it would look like on the command line:

   ```
   java --module-path <path> --module <module>/<main-class>
   ```